# Google Sites storage limit: how can I monitor the situation?

Tags: google-sites

If I understood correctly, **Google Sites** (free account) has a storage limit of 100 MB.
Questions:

1. How do I monitor how many MB I'm using in my web site (made with Google Sites) and how many MB are free?
2. If I insert a video linking to YouTube, visible on the site (but it's on YT) is it counted or not?

Thank you
C.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications!  Please  make an effort to research  questions yourself before asking for a solution.  If you come up short, share what you learned and why it didn't help. Please review  [How do I ask a good question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking at obsolete documentation as the new Google Sites are stored in Google Drive; they don't have specific storage space. The 100 MB storage limit is a feature of the Classic Google Sites, but sites created using this app can't be edited and it's not possible to create new sites using this app.

To learn about the new Google Sites features, go to https://support.google.com/sites.